# Conditionally splitting a string on a complex delimiter

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have the following String:

> 1,2,3|5,4,5|8

I want the output like this:

> 1,2,3|5
>   4,5|8

How can I achieve this using java?
I mean to split with `","`, but only if it's after a `"|"`.

Comment: you may use [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for this

Comment: You may want to look at Regex : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) condition, for example:

```
"1,2,3|5,4,5|8".split("(?<=\\|\\d{1,10}),"))
```

Lookbehind condition `(?<=\\|\\d{1,10})` means: `|` followed by up to 10 digits (as lookbehind requires defined maximum length, unbounded repetition modifiers as `+` or `*` cannot be used).

Comment: Thanks @Sasha Salauyou. It's Working

Comment: And Sasha one more Question Can I achieve same through Sql server..?

Comment: @QuestionWarriors sorry, I don't know. You may ask some db specialist for that, tagging question as [sql] or [sqlserver]

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to use lookbehind:

```
for (String s : "1,2,3|5,4,5|8".split("(?<=\\|\\d{1,20}),")) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

The above prints

```
1,2,3|5
4,5|8
```

Note that Java regex has a limitation that lookarounds must have an obvious upper length. Hence, you need to use `\\d{1,20}` in place of a more natural `\\d+`.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/ePFoEN)

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
split("(?<=\\|[0-9]),")
```

Here:

- In `(?<=\\|[0-9])`

  - `?<=` denoted positive lookbehind.
  - `\\|[0-9]` denotes that there is a | and a digit before the `,`.
- `,` matches the `,`

Answer (score 0):

if you just need to output,

```
final String[] p = x.split(",");

for (int i=0; i<p.length; i++) {
    if (i>0 && p[i-1].contains("|"))
        System.out.print("\n");
    else
        System.out.print(",");
    System.out.print(p[i]);
}
//if (p.length>0)   
    System.out.print("\n");
```